# Where did I go wrong when using ARMAacf function in R?

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, acf-pacf

I recently had an exam in forecasting where I was one point short of an A. The biggest mistake I made which cost me 3 points was that I incorrectly used the ARMAacf() function to calculate the implied ACF and PACF. I want to understand how I can use it correctly in the future.

The model was an ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,1,1)[4] w/drift model with coefficients ar1 = 0.9, sma1 = -0.4, drift = 1.4. Based on what I read on http://www.craigmile.com/peter/teaching/6550/notes/acf_pacf_in_R.pdf about the function, and the ar1 coefficient in my model which is 0.9, I used the ARMAacf like this:

```
ARMAacf(ar=0.9, ma=0, lag.max=10, pacf=T)
```

When asking about the correct way (we never had anything in the lectures remotely about this) he said I should multiply the polynomials together to get the correct ar/ma form.

Could someone show me an example of how they would use the ar and/or ma coefficients in the ARMAacf function for future reference?

Comment: This is in danger of being closed here as it looks like a question about programming in R. I suspect though there is a statistical point here so could you edit the question to bring out the statistical issue?

Comment: I agree with @mdewey . It is unclear whether you are asking about R functions or the underlying statistics.  If it is about the latter, then it's on topic, but needs to be reworded.